# How to represent a column name with a variable in orderBy of scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
 for (e <- arr02) {
      val df = t04.select("session_id", e)  // right
      val w = Window.partitionBy($"session_id").orderBy($e.desc)  //error
}
```

e is a string variable, the method `.orderBy($e.desc)`  `e` is wrong, `.orderBy($"column_name".desc)` is right.

Then how can I represent a column name with a variable in `orderBy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sql.functions.col`, for your case:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val w = Window.partitionBy($"session_id").orderBy(col(e).desc)
```

---

*Example:*

```
val df = Seq(("a",2),("b",4)).toDF("A", "B")    

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

df.orderBy($"A".desc).show
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  b|  4|
|  a|  2|
+---+---+
```

With variable as column name:

```
val e = "A"
df.orderBy($e.desc).show
```

> ```
> <console>:27: error: not found: value $e
>        df.orderBy($e.desc).show
>                   ^
> ```

Use `col` to construct the column from string:

```
df.orderBy(col(e).desc).show
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  b|  4|
|  a|  2|
+---+---+
```

Comment: thank you. From the above dataframe If I want another dataframe with columns from  A i.e  b, a  and from B the values of b and a colum .....

And  the data is 
'
----------
|  b | a |
----------
| 4  | 2 |
----------

'